# Run specflow tag from within visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I've got an automation suite using SpecFlow. Some of my test scenarios are tagged with let's say `@testme`

How can I run all the `@testme` tags from within visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freely adopted from: http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/using-tags-in-specflow-features.html

If the test framework supports it (as NUnit and MsTest do) the tags will be converted to Categories which you can use to run certain parts of your test suite for example.

Turning on the categories is typically done with ordering/grouping your test cases by traits. (Visual Studio 2017 Community: Test Explorer, 2nd icon: Group By: Traits)

Comment: Grouping by traits shows me all my tags. This is what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!